# Find the Conditional Distribution of X

Tags: probability, density-function

Let N have a Bin(100, 1/4) distribution. Given that N = n, flip a fair coin n times, and let X be the number of heads observed. Find the conditional distribution of X given that N = n. Be precise about the possible values and a proper conditional probability mass function

I'm really stumped on this one. So far I concluded P(X | N=n) = P(X, N=n)/P(N=n). I don't know where to go from here. I also know that the p.m.f./p.d.f. of Bin(n,p) is (nCk)*(p^k)*(1-p)^(n-k) but I don't know how to apply it to this question.

Comment: Given $N=n$, you should have $X \sim Bin(n,\frac12)$ and the support of $X$ is $\{0,1,2,\ldots, n\}$.  More interesting is the unconditional distribution of $X$, which you could show is $X \sim Bin(100,\frac18)$

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and you're overthinking it. Conditional on $N=n$ just means that we are considering the case when there are $n$ flips of the fair coin. The conditional distribution is thus $Bin(n,p)$ so $$ P(X=k \mid N=n) = \frac{1}{2^n}{n \choose k}$$ for $k=0,1,\ldots n.$

Comment: How did you get your final answer? I'm still confused

Comment: The number of heads in $n$ independent coinflips of a fair coin is binomial(n,1/2). I just plugged in the formula that you wrote down. As to why it's binomial, say that the probability of heads is $p.$ Any string with $k$ heads and $n-k$ tails has probability $p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ and there are ${n\choose k}$ different possible strings with $k$ heads (you just pick which $k$ are heads... that's $k$ choices from $n$ options).

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be a little different since p = 1/4?

Comment: No, for $n$ flips of a *fair coin* the distribution for the head count is indeed: $\mathcal{Binom}(n, 1/2)$.

Comment: @ChanceGordon $p=1/4$ is for the distribution of $N,$ which has nothing to do with the distribution of $X$ given $N=n.$ The $p=1/2$ is cause it's a fair coin... probability of heads is $1/2.$

Answer (score 0):

Don't over think.

When given that $n$ coins have been fliped, what is the distribution for the count of heads among those $n$ flips?